# How to change java compiler warning to error

Tags: ant, preferences

I'm trying to change java compiler warning to error and error to warning.
For example:

```
fallthroughCase=error
nullReference=error
enumIdentifier=error
וnusedObjectAllocation=warning
redundantNullCheck=warning`
```

It is easily done on the Eclipse environment, but I haven't found a way to do the same on our build server ANT build.

Any help would be mostly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dror